# Why does the xml.sax parser in Jython 2.5.2 turn two-character attributes in to tuples?

Tags: python, xml, jython, sax

When ever I encounter a 2-character attribute in my XML stream when parsing with xml.sax under Jython 2.5.2 it converts the attribute name to a tuple. No amount of coercion of that name allows me to extract the value for the attribute. I tried passing the tuple or converting it to a string and passing that. Both cases result in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 18, in startElement
    print '%s = %s' % (k, attrs.getValue(k))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.5.2/libexec/Lib/xml/sax/drivers2/drv_javasax.py", line 266, in getValue
    value = self._attrs.getValue(_makeJavaNsTuple(name))
TypeError: getValue(): 1st arg can't be coerced to String, int
```

I've got some sample code you can run that shows the problem:

```
import xml
from xml import sax
from xml.sax import handler
import traceback

class MyXMLHandler( handler.ContentHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def startElement(self, name, attrs):
        for k in attrs.keys():            
            print 'type(k) = %s' % type(k)
            if isinstance(k, (list, tuple)):    
                k = ''.join(k)
            print 'type(k) = %s' % type(k)
            print 'k = %s' % k
            try:
                print '%s = %s' % (k, attrs.getValue(k))
            except Exception, e:
                print '\nError:'
                traceback.print_exc()
                print ''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = '<TAG A="0" AB="0" ABC="0"/>'
    print '%s' % s
    xml.sax.parseString(s, MyXMLHandler())
    exit(0)
```

When run, the `AB` attribute is returned as a tuple but the `A` and `ABC` attributes are unicode strings and function properly with the `get()` method on the [Attribute object](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.sax.reader.html#attributes-objects). Under Jython 2.5.2 this outputs, for me:

```
>  jython test.py
<TAG A="0" AB="0" ABC="0"/>
type(k) = <type 'unicode'>
type(k) = <type 'unicode'>
k = A
A = 0
type(k) = <type 'tuple'>
type(k) = <type 'unicode'>
k = AB

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 18, in startElement
    print '%s = %s' % (k, attrs.getValue(k))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.5.2/libexec/Lib/xml/sax/drivers2/drv_javasax.py", line 266, in getValue
    value = self._attrs.getValue(_makeJavaNsTuple(name))
TypeError: getValue(): 1st arg can't be coerced to String, int

type(k) = <type 'unicode'>
type(k) = <type 'unicode'>
k = ABC
ABC = 0
```

This code functions correctly under Python 2.7.2 on OS X and Python 2.4.3 on CentOS 5.6. I dug around Jython bugs but couldn't find anything similar to this issue.

Is it a known Jython xml.sax handling problem? Or have I messed up something in my Handler that's 2.5.2 incompatible?

---

Edit: this appears to be a Jython 2.5.2 bug. I found a reference to it: http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=27783080 -- suggestions for a workaround welcome.

Answer (score 0):

So, this is a reported bug in Jython. It took some digging but I found it in their bug archive:

http://bugs.jython.org/issue1768

The second comment on the bug provides a work-around for the issue: use the `_attrs.getValue()` method to retrieve values off the attributes list. Like so:

```
attrs._attrs.getValue('id')
```

My re-written code works if I change the line:

```
print '%s = %s' % (k, attrs.getValue(k))
```

to:

```
print '%s = %s' % (k, attrs._attrs.getValue(k))
```

The more flexible works-in-python-and-jython solution is to build a helper:

```
def _attrsGetValue(attrs, name, default=None):
    value = None
    if 'jython' in sys.executable.lower():
        value = attrs._attrs.getValue(name)
        if not name:
            value = default
    else:
        value = attrs.get(name, default)
    return value
```